# Unable to Update Data on Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, updating

I am unable to update data on my firestore database. I entered new data and clicked the Save Task button but nothing would happen.. I am not sure where the problem is. My code is below:

```
 saveTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String taskName = name.getText().toString();
            String taskDate = tDate.getText().toString();
            String startTime = sTime.getText().toString();
            String endTime = eTime.getText().toString();
            String taskTag = tTag.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String notes = tNotes.getText().toString();
            String stat = Status.getText().toString();

            userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            taskRef = fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId).collection("tasks").document();
            taskRef.update("taskName",taskName);
            taskRef.update("taskDate",taskDate);
            taskRef.update("startTime",startTime);
            taskRef.update("endTime",endTime);
            taskRef.update("taskTag",taskTag);
            taskRef.update("notes",notes);
            taskRef.update("status", stat);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any error shown in the logcat output of your app when you run the `taskRef.update(...)` statements?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intend to create a new document:

```
taskRef = fStore
    .collection("usersData")
    .document(userId)
    .collection("tasks")
    .document();
```

Passing no value to `document()` says that you want a document with a random ID, which will be unique.

Given that this is going to be a new document that doesn't exist yet, you won't be able to use `update()` on it, since `update()` on documents that don't exist will always fail.  If you check the results of each `update()`, you actually see that they each fail.

What you probably want to do instead is use `set()` to create a new document, and pass it a Map of all the fields you want to add to the new document, as illustrated by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

Comment: This sounds likely. Shouldn't the `update` statements be throwing an error in that case though?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The returned Task should generate an error, but I wouldn't necessarily count on something showing up in the log by default.

Comment: You should check the Task returned by `update()` to determine if it worked or not, and if not, what happened.  The documentation shows examples.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Answer (score 0):

there is any error print? 
correct me if im wrong, you have collection of `userData` which contain a structure with tasks and you want to add to it new task? if its the scenario you should get it from the `userData` document like that:

```
userRef = await fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId);
await userRef.get().then(async function(querySnapshot){
let userData = await querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
await userData.update(tasks: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                       taskName: taskName,
                       taskDate: taskDate,
                       startTime: startTime,
                              .
                              .
                              .
     }));
```

if still not work please print the `taskRef` to see if its a `DocumentReference`

Comment: taskref is a document reference. I had declared it above as DocumentReference taskref

Comment: i tried printing in the console... I got  `I/System.out: com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@d6b7f20e` @AmitKalo

Comment: I dont want to add a new task. I want to update the task. With the userData collection I have another collection called Tasks with various documents in it. I want to update a task

Comment: When it came to deleting  a task, I used `taskRef.delete();` but the document wasn't deleted. so I'm not sure what part of the code is wrong

Comment: so first you need to get the ref to the task, i suggest you to add to every task a property of the user and to take the tasks like that:
`await fStore.collection("Tasks").where("userId", "==", userId);`
then update like i mention in the answer.

Comment: or if you have on user an array of tasks you should get it like that:
`await fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId).get().then(async function(querySnapshot){
let userData = await querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
userData.tasks //here you have the array of user tasks
}`

Comment: would i have to also specific my taskID? since its a particular task in collection "tasks" that must be deleted

Comment: The code in the second comment pull the userData of the required user, and the last line is the user tasks

Comment: Your problem is that you do a wrong access to the taskRef